# Discriminant of non-degenerated Billinearform is square in Ideal Class Group

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $K= Frac(A)$ its field of fractions and
$V$ a $n$-dimensional vector space over $K$.
A *lattice* of $V$ (with respect to ring $A$) is a sub-$A$-module $X$ of $V$
that is finitely generated and spans $V$.

Let $n= \dim_K V$ and assume $V$ is endowed with a *non-degenerate
bilinear form* $T(v, w)$. It is known that $T$ extends to a non-degenerate bilinear
form (again denoted by $T$) on the exterior algebra of $V$, and, in particular,
on $W:= \wedge^n V$. This form induces by non-degeneracy and dimensional reasons
an isomorphism

$$ T: W \otimes_K W \to K.  $$

Let again $X$ be a lattice of $V$, and let $X_W$ be it' s $n$-th exterior power,
identified with a lattice of $W$. The image of $X_W \otimes_A X_W$ under $T$ is
a non-zero *fractional ideal* of $K$, which is called the *discriminant* of $X$
with respect to $T$; we denote it by $D_{X,T}$.

In Serre's 'Local Fields' at page 49 is remarked:

> The above definition shows that $D_{X,T}$ is isomorphic as an $A$-module
> to $X_W \otimes_A X_W$; its ideal class (modulo the principal ideals) is thus
> a square.

I not understand it. Why is the class of $D_{X,T}$ in the
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group

a square. The *ideal class group*  is the quotient group $J_K/P_K$ where
$J_K$ is the group of fractional ideals of the ring $A$, and $P_K$ is its subgroup
of principal ideals with operation = ideal multiplication. Therefore the claim
is equivalent to existence of an nonzero element $a \in A$ and a fractional ideal
$\frak{f}$ such that $D_{X,T}= \frak{f}^2 \cdot (a)$ where $(a)= a \cdot A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that the ideal class group of $A$ is equivalently its Picard group. This is to say, it is the group of $A$-modules which are locally free of rank $1$ (i.e. modules $M$ s.t. $M_{\mathfrak p}\simeq A_{\mathfrak p}$ for all prime ideal $\mathfrak p\subset A$) with group operation given by tensor products. Hence, saying that $D_{X,T}\simeq X_W\otimes_AX_W$ exactly says that is is a square in the Picard group.

In terms of fractional ideals, fix some nonzero $x\in X_W\subset W$, and let $\mathfrak f=T(X_W\otimes x)\subset K$. Note that $\mathfrak f$ is a fractional ideal. I claim that $\mathfrak f^2=D_{X,T}\cdot(a)$, where $a:=T(x\otimes x)$, inside $K$. It suffices to check this equality locally, i.e. to check that $(\mathfrak fA_{\mathfrak p})^2=D_{X,T}\cdot aA_{\mathfrak p}\subset K$ for all primes $\mathfrak p\subset A$.

Hence, we may assume that $A$ is a dvr (and in particular a PID). Then, $X_W$ is finitely generated and torsion free over the PID $A$, so free as an $A$-module; now, $X_W\otimes_AK=W$ is rank $1$ over $K$, so we conclude that $X_W$ is rank one over $A$. Hence, $\mathfrak f^2$ is generated by elements of the form
$$T(\lambda x\otimes x)T(\mu x\otimes x)=\lambda\mu T(x\otimes x)^2=\lambda\mu T(x\otimes x)\cdot a\in D_{X,T}\cdot(a)$$
with $\lambda,\mu\in A$, so $\mathfrak f^2\subset D_{X,T}\cdot(a)$. In the other direction, $D_{X,T}\cdot(a)$ is generated by elements of the form
$$T(\lambda x\otimes\mu x)\cdot a=T(\lambda x\otimes\mu x)T(x\otimes x)=\lambda\mu T(x,x)^2=T(\lambda x\otimes x)T(\mu x\otimes x)\in\mathfrak f^2,$$
with $\lambda,\mu\in A$, so also $D_{X,T}\cdot(a)\subset\mathfrak f^2$.

Comment: I understand your argument up to one point. Why $\mathrm{rank}_AX_W=1$? By constrction $X_W \subset W \cong K$ is a sub-$A$-module, but I see no obvious reason why it should have rank $1$. The number of generators of lattice $X \subset V=K^n$ as $A$-module also in general not equals $n$

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the definition of "lattice" to carry the assumption that it's free of rank equal to the dimension of the ambient vector space. I think one can still show that $\mathfrak f^2=D_{X,T}\cdot(a)$ by checking locally. If you replace $A$ with $A_{\mathfrak p}$ then you're working over a PID, so now lattices really will be free of the expected rank, and the above argument should go through.